# Android google drive file change listener not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have registered the change listener to google drive file as follows-

```
DriveFile driveFile = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, mSelectedFileId);
driveFile.addChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient,changeListener);


 final private Listener<ChangeEvent> changeListener = new Listener<ChangeEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ChangeEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

when i changing file content through web browser,then change listener is called.What is correct way to listen drive file changes?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean change listener isn't called.

Changes made on the web won't immediately be reflected on the device. It will happen the next time that the device finds out about updates.  You can speed that up by interacting with the API, or calling requestSync.

Comment: I've tried to implement it on both DriveFolder and DriveFile with no luck. Just not getting any listener hits at all. Tried fiddling with 'starred' on the web Drive, changing both meta (title) and contents using GDAA methods in code, requestSync(), but to no avail. Any hints on debugging this? Manifest setting?

Comment: Also, per your comment "Changes made on the web won't immediately be reflected". Isn't it defeating the purpose of notifications? Are we talking milliseconds or hours (on wifi)?

Comment: You should be immediately notified of changes made to the file from the same device while you have an active change listener.  If you aren't, you must not be setting it up right.  It doesn't require any manifest settings.

Comment: I hope to fix it soon, but this is not the point. To be notified about change from the SAME device? The app does not need that. It needs to be notified if the change takes place on another device or a different app accessing the same data, right? Or at least to know what the latency is. The statements about the latency are quite ambiguous so far. For instance, anytime other device modifies / deletes a file I always have to resort to polling (with RESTful). I was hoping for the same latency as in the realtime Api.

Comment: Any chance this is working for anyone? Am trying the google demo example listed here.https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/events/ListenChangeEventsForFilesActivity.java  Not able to lister for any activities even after waiting for hours.

Comment: I have the same problem. My logs show that it has worked at least once, but I can't find out when it does and when it doesn't...