# Drive Android Api. How to get notified or invoke listner when something has changed in the folder from web?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I want to get File Or Folder ID when that file is changed from the web. I gone through Documentation [Listening for Change Events](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events)  [Git Hub Demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/events/ListenChangeEventsForFilesActivity.java)   But i am not able to implement it.
**In my app i am trying to listen to changes and modify those changes to local files also (sync).**

In this test code i am just creating a folder and attaching a listner to the folder.
but when i rename folder from web Listner in not listening why?

1>I tried with this code

```
DriveId ddid = sky.getDriveFolder().getDriveId();
        DriveFolder df = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, ddid);
        df.addChangeListener(getGoogleApiClient(), changeListener2);
```

2> And also with this line

```
 DriveFolderResult sky = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
            .createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).await();
 sky.getDriveFolder().addChangeListener(getGoogleApiClient(), changeListener2);
```

class file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {


private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;
private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;


private ContentsResult contentsresult;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

String EXISTING_FILE_ID = "";
int folderCreated = 0;
SharedPreferences prefs;
ArrayList<String> dbfileid = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dbfilename = new ArrayList<String>();

String fdd="";
DriveFolderResult sky;
private DriveId mFolderDriveId;
String isfolder;
SharedPreferences sp;
String Shared="Shared";
String folderid="";

 int j=0;
 String songfileid="";


    String realid ="";


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    initDrive();

}

private void initDrive() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.API)
                .addScope(com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive.SCOPE_FILE).setAccountName("shivrajp130@gmail.com")
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.

    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        showToast("Error in on connection failed");
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        showToast("error" + e.toString());

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    showToast("Inside Connected");
     sp = getSharedPreferences(Shared, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showToast("Thread Started");

            createSkyFolder();
        }
    });

     t.start();

}



private void createSkyFolder()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {
      showToast("creating Folder");

     if(!sp.getString(isfolder, "false").contains("created"))
     {

        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().
                                        setTitle("Sky folder").build();

        sky = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
            .createFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).await();

        sky.getDriveFolder().addChangeListener(getGoogleApiClient(), changeListener2);

        showToast("folder created");

        sp.edit().putString(isfolder, "created").commit();

    //  To store secret ID string of file or folder so that we can later get a DriveId object.

         realid = sky.getDriveFolder().getDriveId().encodeToString();

         sp.edit().putString(folderid, realid).commit();
         showToast("Real== "+realid);


     }

    Status s = Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).await();
         if(s.isSuccess())
            {
                showToast("Success");
            }
   }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        showToast("Connected");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}




public void showToast(final String toast) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}




public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    return mGoogleApiClient;
}






    final private Listener<ChangeEvent> changeListener2 = new Listener<ChangeEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(ChangeEvent event) {
            showToast("Listening now");
            showToast(String.format("The New Id Is    %s", event.hasMetadataChanged()));
        }
    };



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    showToast("GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
}
```

Please provide any code snippet for the same.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778501/android-google-drive-file-change-listener-not-working/22789025#22789025

Comment: ya.. can you give me a example code which does it. Like when any changes happens from the web it will be shown in the app (Invoke Listner) not immediately but may be after some time also.