# Google Drive Android Api ChangeEvent Listener workings

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I am abusing this forum to solicit explanation (from the GDAA support team) of intended use of GDAA Notification Feature. The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events) is quite sufficient to implement it, and the two related SO questions [22980497](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980497/google-drive-android-api-change-notifications-not-working) and [22778501](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778501/android-google-drive-file-change-listener-not-working) touch on the same subject. But I can't get my head around it's intended use. 
Here is the example.

- Device A 'touches' the Drive object and gets notification immediately.
- Device B 'touches' the same Drive object and the device A gets notified '*sometime later*', even if both devices are on wifi.

So, what is it good for? The app on one particular device knows that it just modified an object, does not need to be notified. On the other hand, if it gets notification that another device modified object with a CONSIDERABLE (minutes) delay, how can synchronization be implemented? Or how can it be used at all? I was advised to use 'requestSync()', but did not see any difference (besides, how it is different from direct polling).
Today, I can reliably synchronize multiple devices by polling, but can't make it work with notifications that do not notify on time.